# How to write a TeXstudio macro for the `\replaced` command in the `changes` package?

Tags: texstudio

I would like to use TeXstudio macros to ease the usage of the `changes` package.

For `\added` and `\deleted`, it is easy to write the corresponding macros.

```
// add
if (!cursor.hasSelection()) {
    editor.replaceSelectedText( "\\added{%|}", {"macro": true} )
}
// delete
if (cursor.hasSelection()) {
    editor.replaceSelectedText( "\\deleted{%< %>}", {"macro": true} )
}
```

Note that TeXstudio supports **multiple cursors / block selection**, and these two macros take that feature into consideration.

For `\replaced{}{}`, I would like to place the selected content into the second curly brace while place the cursor into the first curly brace.

```
if (cursor.hasSelection()) {
    txt = cursor.selectedText();
    editor.insertSnippet("\\replaced{")
    editor.replaceSelectedText( "%|}{"+txt+"}", {"macro": true} )
}
```

The macro above does a good job when there is only one cursor, but it fails when there are multiple cursors. I would like to improve its safety either by having support for multiple cursors or by making it only active when there is only one cursor.

**Update**

I find a solution which operates only one cursor (see my answer below). Now this question boils down to find a solution which support multiple cursors.

Answer (score 1):

By some trials, here is a macro for the `\replaced` command; this macro handles only one cursor and ignores the others. The point is that `cursor.*` functions operate only one cursor and `editor.selectNothing()` clears all cursors.

```
%SCRIPT
if (cursor.hasSelection()) {
    txt = cursor.selectedText()
    cursor.removeSelectedText()
    editor.selectNothing()
    cursor.insertText("\\replaced{")
    line = cursor.lineNumber()
    column = cursor.columnNumber()
    cursor.insertText("}{"+txt+"}")
    cursor.moveTo(line, column)
}
```

The [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#JAVASCRIPT-MACROS) does not say which cursor `cursor.*` functions operate; in my environment the macro above operates the first cursor and ignores the others.

Hope it is helpful.